# "...И его холодное дыхание грозило близкой бурею..." - поясняет ли часть перед двоеточием?

Tags: пунктуация

По правилам общей может быть поясняемая двумя частями сложносочиненного предложения третья часть, предшествующая им и связанная с ними бессоюзной связью: 
Одно было ясно: ссора оказалась окончательной и назад он не вернётся;

Тогда почему в этом предложении стоит запятая перед "и":

Вот, наконец, мы взобрались на Гуд-гору, остановились и оглянулись: на ней висело серое облако, и его холодное дыхание грозило близкой бурею… (Лермонтов).

Каковы отношения между тремя частями этого предложения?

Answer (score 3):

***(1) Вот, наконец, мы взобрались на Гуд-гору, остановились и оглянулись: (2) на ней висело серое облако, (3) и его холодное дыхание грозило близкой бурею…***

Сложное предложение включает три простых предложения. Между предложением (1) и (2) бессоюзная изъяснительная связь, но к предложению (3) эта связь не относится.

Здесь имеется в виду: **оглянулись и увидели**, что над ней висело серое облако. Предложение (3) — это последующий вывод из того, что увидели.

Соответственно бессоюзная связь **не объединяет** предложения 2 и 3, запятая ставится.

Answer (score 2):

Часть предложения после "и" поясняет не первую, а вторую часть:

> Висело серое облако, и его холодное дыхание грозило близкой бурею.

Поэтому первая часть не является общей для последующих двух.